# Include sub class automatically

Tags: php, slim

I don't know the terminology for my problem so I am asking here for the solution since I can't find it by searching.

I am making a simple rest API where I have specified my Routes.php

In my index.php I call the routes:

```
$routes = new Routes();
$routes->getRoutes();
```

app/Routes.php

```
<?php

/* All default application routes go here. Flow specific routes are implemented in the specific flows directory. */

class Routes extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        /* Inherit stuff from Controller */
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getRoutes()
    {

        /* Routes */
        $this->app->group('/api', function () use ($app)
        {

            $this->app->get('/cron/run', 'Cron:run');

        });
    }
}
```

Now I want it to support standalone "modules".

So we add a module and its routes in here:

app/MyModule/Routes.php

Imagine multiple modules in here with their own routes.

Here is the problem.

How can I add routes in all these modules to be included automatically in the application routes?

**I do not want to override.**

I am using Slim PHP framework if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to instantiate each module's `Routes` class in turn within your bootstrapping process (i.e. before you call `run()`).

As long as each module defines a unique string for the group's URL (`/api` in your example), then they won't clash.